# TCP Linux server lock after the first accept

Tags: c

I am writing a TCP client in C.
Following several tutorial I wrote my code but it can accept only the first connection to the server.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr for INADDR_ANY
#include <string.h> //for splitting (strtok)
#include <pthread.h> //thread library
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h> //for function close()

void* SocketHandler(void*);


int main(void) {
    //socket parameters
    int server_socket_desc;
    int clientAddressLength = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;

    const unsigned short int PORT_NUMBER = 8963;
server_socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (server_socket_desc < -1) {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }
    puts("Socket created");

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;  //it should be always set to AF_INET
    //set the server address
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.123.240");
    //server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("31.185.101.35");
    //server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT_NUMBER);

    //Bind
    if (bind(server_socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr,
            sizeof(server_addr)) < 0) {
        //print the error message
        perror("bind failed. Error");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("bind done");

    //Listen
    listen(server_socket_desc, 10);

    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");

    //accept connection from an incoming client
    while (1) {
        int *temp_socket_desc = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
        if ((*temp_socket_desc = accept(server_socket_desc,
                (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr,
                (socklen_t*) &clientAddressLength)) != -1) {

            printf("----------\nConnection accepted \n");
            sleep(1);
            pthread_t thread_id;
            int *client_socket_desc = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
            client_socket_desc = temp_socket_desc;

            pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, &SocketHandler,
                    (void*)     client_socket_desc);
            //if thread has not terminated, pthread_detach() shall not cause it to terminate
            pthread_detach(thread_id);
            puts("handler assigned");

        } else
            puts("connection refused");

    }

    close(server_socket_desc);
    //mysql_close(mysql_conn);
    return 0;
}

/*
 * This will handle connection for each client
 * */
void* SocketHandler(void* lp) {
    int *csock = (int*) lp;

    char buffer[128];
    int buffer_len = 128;
    int bytecount;
    memset(buffer, 0, buffer_len);
    if ((bytecount = read(*csock, buffer, buffer_len) == -1)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error receiving data\n");
        close(*csock);
        return 0;
    }
    printf("Received bytes %d\nReceived string \"%s\"\n", bytecount, buffer);

    close(*csock);
    free(csock);
    puts("exiting thread");
    //pthread_exit(0);
    return 0;
}
```

I temporally solved the problem inserting a **sleep()** after the **while loop** but it is a very bad solution.
Can somebody explain me why the code does'n work without the sleep?

Comment: your code will not compile, you have multiple int *client_socket_desc definition. Please update code correctly & paste output from client & server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem in handling of `client_socket_desc`:

You allocate it only once. All threads will get the same pointer. 
So later accepts will override socket descriptors value of earlier threads.

Try the following change, for allocating own memory block for each thread:

```
int fd = accept( server_socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, (socklen_t*)                
                 &clientAddressLength)
if ( fd != -1 ) 
{           
    pthread_t thread_id;
    int *client_socket_desc = malloc(sizeof(int));

    *client_socket_desc = fd;

    pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, &SocketHandler,(void*) client_socket_desc);
    ...
```

Or course you must add error handlings for malloc and pthread_create. 
And also free the allocated memory when not needed anymore.

I don't understood why there is the following code in the while loop:

```
if(send(*client_socket_desc,buffer,1,MSG_NOSIGNAL)>0)
{
    puts("closing client socket");
    close(*client_socket_desc);
}
```

Close client sockets in client handler threads.

Comment: Tank you for the answer, now I have much more clear how the thread works but the code still accept only the first connection I am updating my code in the first post